# Code working in jsfiddle but throws an error in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

Hi the following code works fine on jsfiddle on Chrome browser, provided the browser is opened in disabled web security mode.
[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/dkdnaxaq/4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=dkdnaxaq)

**I have placed my script inside a document.ready handler** but browser throws the following error saying "getData is not defined":
[image: console error]

In the debugger, here is where the code breaks to throw an error:

[image: debugger]

Here's my HTML code as well:

```
<html>

<body>
    <iframe src="https://news.ycombinator.com/" width="800" height="500" id="idframe"></iframe>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            debugger;
            var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            iframe = document.getElementById('idframe');
            var url = iframe.src;
            var getData = function(data) {
                if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.resources && data.query.results.resources.content && data.query.results.resources.status == 200) loadHTML(data.query.results.resources.content);
                else if (data && data.error && data.error.description) loadHTML(data.error.description);
                else loadHTML('Error: Cannot load ' + url);
            };
            var loadURL = function(src) {
                url = src;
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.headers%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=getData';
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            };
            var loadHTML = function(html) {
                iframe.src = 'about:blank';
                iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
                iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="' + url + '"><scr' + 'ipt>document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") { e.preventDefault(); parent.loadURL(e.target.href); } });</scr' + 'ipt>'));
                iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
            }

            loadURL(iframe.src);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Syntax goes like this: if (condition) { return } else if (condition) { return } else {return}. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @AivarasP May be it is. Because I tried to run it with only loadHTML('Error: Cannot load the page '); inside getData but this message isn't shown in the iframe somehow!

Answer (score 0):

The source `'https://news.ycombinator.com/'` you are trying to load to the iframe is prohibited to be used with iframes using HTTP response header `X-Frame-Options` which is set to `DENY`. So it can never be loaded within an iframe.

This is done for security reasons in order to prevent threats like

(Clickjacking) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

(Cross-Site_Request_Forgery)https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

The fiddle is not working as well and throws the same error in console.

Comment: The fiddle works for me. You may try loading the fiddle in disabled web security mode though. The fiddle was in fact a solution I found for overcoming the “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options” issue